# How to create a reusable react-hook-form component with TypeScript generics?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

`Person` component is reused in two different forms:

**Person.tsx**

```js
import { UseFormReturn } from "react-hook-form";
import { FieldPaths } from "./types";

type Props<TFormValues> = {
  methods: UseFormReturn<TFormValues>;
  fieldPaths: FieldPaths<TFormValues>;
};

const Person = <TFormValues,>({
  methods,
  fieldPaths
}: Props<TFormValues>) => {
  const { register } = methods;

  return (
    <div className="person">
      <div className="name-field">
        <input {...register(fieldPaths.firstName)} placeholder="First name" />
        <input {...register(fieldPaths.lastName)} placeholder="Last name" />
      </div>
      <div className="radio-group">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" value="free" {...register(fieldPaths.status)} />{" "}
          Free
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" value="busy" {...register(fieldPaths.status)} />{" "}
          Busy
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export { Person };
```

**SimpleForm.tsx**

```js
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { Person } from "./Person";
import { TPerson } from "./types";
import { emptyPerson } from "./utils";

type SimpleFormValues = {
  person: TPerson;
};

const simpleFormFieldPaths = {
  firstName: "person.name.first",
  lastName: "person.name.last",
  status: "person.status"
} as const;

const SimpleForm = () => {
  const methods = useForm<SimpleFormValues>({
    defaultValues: {
      person: emptyPerson
    }
  });
  const { handleSubmit } = methods;
  const onSubmit = ({ person }: SimpleFormValues) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(person, null, 2));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Simple form</h2>
      <form method="post" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Person methods={methods} fieldPaths={simpleFormFieldPaths} />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export { SimpleForm };
```

**ComplexForm.tsx**

```js
import { useFieldArray, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { Person } from "./Person";
import { TPerson } from "./types";
import { emptyPerson } from "./utils";

type ComplexFormValues = {
  artists: TPerson[];
};

const ComplexForm = () => {
  const methods = useForm<ComplexFormValues>({
    defaultValues: {
      artists: [emptyPerson, emptyPerson, emptyPerson]
    }
  });
  const { control, handleSubmit } = methods;
  const { fields } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "artists"
  });
  const onSubmit = ({ artists }: ComplexFormValues) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(artists, null, 2));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Complex form</h2>
      <form method="post" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        {fields.map((field, index) => {
          const complexFormFieldPaths = {
            firstName: `artists.${index}.name.first`,
            lastName: `artists.${index}.name.last`,
            status: `artists.${index}.status`
          } as const;

          return (
            <Person
              methods={methods}
              fieldPaths={complexFormFieldPaths}
              key={field.id}
            />
          );
        })}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export { ComplexForm };
```

**types.ts**

```js
import { FieldPath } from "react-hook-form";

export type FieldPaths<TFormValues> = {
  firstName: FieldPath<TFormValues>;
  lastName: FieldPath<TFormValues>;
  status: FieldPath<TFormValues>;
};

export type TPerson = {
  name: {
    first: string;
    last: string;
  };
  status: "" | "free" | "busy";
};
```

**utils.ts**

```js
import { TPerson } from "./types";

export const emptyPerson: TPerson = {
  name: {
    first: "",
    last: ""
  },
  status: ""
};
```

It works beautifully, but if I try to `setValue` in `Person`, TypeScript throws an error:

```js
const { setValue } = methods;

setValue(fieldPaths.firstName, "David");
```

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UnpackNestedValue<PathValue<TFormValues, Path>>'

How could I fix this?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reusable-react-hook-form-component-with-typescript-generics-lpyvfh)

---

I believe what I want is to hint TypeScript that `PathValue(TFormValues, typeof fieldPaths.firstName)` is always going to be a `string`, and then it should work, but I'm not sure how to achieve that.

Note: `PathValue` is defined [here](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/b8a030eff90e240a56e4366b10c02d767951c890/src/types/path/eager.ts#L84).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this used to be fixed in late react-hook-form@6; along had came v7 which reintroduced the problem and seems to have been carried into v8 beta as well.

Regarding your question

> "hint TypeScript that `PathValue(TFormValues, typeof fieldPaths.firstName)` is always going to be a `string`"

This will likely not work, because of what `setValue` has been defined to accept.

Ideally we'd push the issue to the authors and hope for a speedy fix, but in the absence of that, there are two solutions here:

1. Either alias `UnpackNestedValue` and cast to it

   ```
   import { UnpackNestedValue, PathValue, Path } from "react-hook-form";

   type ValueArgument<f> = UnpackNestedValue<PathValue<f, Path<f>>>;

   setValue(fieldPaths.firstName, "David" as ValueArgument<TFormValues>);
   ```
2. Extend the types all the way up to accept primitives

   ```
   import {
     UseFormReturn,
     FieldValues,
     FieldPath,
     UnpackNestedValue,
     FieldPathValue,
     SetValueConfig,
   } from "react-hook-form";
   import { FieldPaths } from "./types";

   type UseMyFormSetValue<TFieldValues extends FieldValues> = <
     TFieldName extends FieldPath<TFieldValues> = FieldPath<TFieldValues>
   >(
     name: TFieldName,
     value: UnpackNestedValue<FieldPathValue<TFieldValues, TFieldName>> | string,
     options?: SetValueConfig
   ) => void;

   interface UseMyFormReturn<TFormValues> extends UseFormReturn<TFormValues> {
     setValue: UseMyFormSetValue<TFormValues>;
   }

   type Props<TFormValues> = {
     methods: UseMyFormReturn<TFormValues>;
     fieldPaths: FieldPaths<TFormValues>;
   };

   const Person = <TFormValues>({ methods, fieldPaths }: Props<TFormValues>) => {
     const { register, setValue } = methods;

     const changeName = () => {
       setValue(fieldPaths.firstName, "David");
     };
   ```